# How can I add "vendor/lib/libvips.42.dylib” in path "node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../../“?

Tags: npm, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

**How can I add "vendor/lib/libvips.42.dylib” in path "node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../../“  ????**

I’m building website with gatsby and I needed to install two gatsby plugins

1. npm install gatsby-plugin-offline
2. npm install gatsby-plugin-manifest

After installing them successfully, I wrote settings for them in gatsby-config.js, and then I gave "gatsby develop" in terminal. But I got errors below.

```
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.050s

⠁ dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _g_once_impl

  Referenced from: /Users/home/Downloads/gatsbyjs-website/gatsbyjs-book-master/mysite/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-manifest/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node

  Expected in: /Users/home/Downloads/gatsbyjs-website/gatsbyjs-book-master/mysite/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../../vendor/lib/libvips.42.dylib


dyld: Symbol not found: _g_once_impl

  Referenced from: /Users/home/Downloads/gatsbyjs-website/gatsbyjs-book-master/mysite/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-manifest/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node

  Expected in: /Users/home/Downloads/gatsbyjs-website/gatsbyjs-book-master/mysite/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../../vendor/lib/libvips.42.dylib


Killed: 9
```

According to the errors, it seems that I have to add "vendor/lib/libvips.42.dylib” in path "node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../../“

***So how can I add "vendor/lib/libvips.42.dylib” in path "node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../../“  ????***

**my node version is  11.13.0**

I’ve installed plugins so far is

- gatsby-plugin-sharp
- gatsby-transformer-sharp
- gatsby-source-filesystem
- gatsby-plugin-react-helemt
- gatsby-plugin-manifest
- gastby-plugin-offline

**my package.json is**

```
{
"name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
"private": true,
"description": "A simplified bare-bones starter for Gatsby",
"version": "0.1.0",
"license": "0BSD",
"scripts": {
"build": "gatsby build",
"develop": "gatsby develop",
"format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
"start": "npm run develop",
"serve": "gatsby serve",
"clean": "gatsby clean",
"test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
},
"dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.12",
"gatsby": "^2.27.0",
"gatsby-image": "^2.5.0",
"gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.7.0",
"gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.5.0",
"gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.5.0",
"gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.8.0",
"gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.5.0",
"gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.6.0",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-helmet": "^6.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"prettier": "2.1.2"
},
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world"
},
"bugs": {
"url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
}

}
```

I would appreciate that if you could give me any advice or help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your `gatsby-config.js`?

Comment: @FerranBuireu sorry for late reply. I found the solution and I needed to install all plugins in using my project that depends on “sharp”. Reference => (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-offline/?=gatsby-plugin-offline). Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved by installing all dependencies and all sharp-related libraries. For more details check: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-offline/?=gatsby-plugin-offline